# mysql query using global variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying run a query to activate a user's account. I am not sure if I am having a problem with the query itself or if there's something else that I don't know about. Here is the code:

```
if($_SESSION['lastid']&&$_SESSION['random'])
{
    $check= mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE id= "$_SESSION[lastid]" AND random = " $_SESSION[random]"');
    $checknum = mysql_num_rows($check);
    //$checknum = mysql_query($check) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $check);
    if($checknum != 0) // run query to activate the account
    {
        $acti= mysql_query('UPDATE members SET activation = "1" WHERE id= "$_SESSION[lastid]"');

        die('Your account has been activated. You may now log in!');
    }
    else
    {
        echo('Invalid id or activation code.') . ' lastid: ' .$_SESSION['lastid'] . ' random: ' .$_SESSION['random'] ;
        // die ('Invalid id or activation code.');
    }
}
else
{
    die('Could not either find id or random number!');  
}
```

this is the warning I am getting from mysql:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
        resource in /hermes/bosweb26b/b2501/servername/folder/file.php on line 30
```

but when I echo the variables out, I get the same values that are stored in the database:

```
Invalid id or activation code. lastid: 2 and random: 36308075
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the $check and $acti variables? I would guess your answer can be found by investigating that.

Comment: yeah, but now i am more lost than ever.... The code is not giving me any errors, but it's not updating the database either... do you have any idea about what i need to do? I am trying to teach myself php.

Answer (score 2):

Your query string is invalid. You're using single quotes (`'`) which means PHP will not interpolate your session variable. it'll search for a literal string that looks like `$_SESSION[...]` instead.

If you had proper error checking on your query call, you'd have seen the syntax error.

```
$check= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id= '{$_SESSION['lastid']}' AND random = {$_SESSION['random']}");
                    ^                                ^^          ^      ^  ^              ^          ^      ^ ^^
if ($check === FALSE) {
    die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Note the `^`, which indicate where the query call has changed. The same changes are required on your second `$acti` query as well. Never **EVER** assume a query succeeds. Even if the SQL syntax itself is perfectly (and yours isn't), there's far too many OTHER reasons that fall outside the control of your code that could cause failure.

Comment: Thanks. The code works, but why it's not updating the database?

Comment: Did you change the update query to use double-quotes as well? Did you add the error checking code?